# Find word within a text block that contains specific key using plain bash (e.g. grep/sed/awk)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have log file like this

```
...
START_WORD
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Bingo1
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Bingo2
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Pokeman1
  some lines (not fixed number)
END_WORD
  more lines
START_WORD
  some lines (not fixed number) 
  Pokeman2
  some lines (not fixed number)
END_WORD
  more lines
START_WORD
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Bingo1
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Bingo2
  some lines (not fixed number)
  Pokeman3
  some lines (not fixed number)
END_WORD
...
```

I would like to bash script that catches those pokeman who are within text block within "START_WORD" and "END_WORD" and where the other words "Bingo1" and "Bingo1" must exists. For exampl, in the above text, it would be Pokeman1 and Pokeman3.

Comment: What is question ? What have you tried till this time ?

Comment: try `awk -v RS=END_WORD '/Bingo1/ && /Bingo2/' ip.txt | grep -o 'Pokeman.*'`

Comment: Hi, I tried using grep with context and then looping over it. Sundeep your answer works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Sundeep, Do you have any suggestion, if there would be some text between END_WORD and "START_WORD"?

Comment: you need to add that info in question...

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/START_WORD/{b=1} /END_WORD/{b=0} 
       b&&/Bingo1/{b+=2} b&&/Bingo2/{b+=4} 
       b==7&&/Pokeman/' file

  Pokeman1
  Pokeman3
```

Comment: Your answer provides great hint. As far as I understand you put statement "Bingo1/{b+=2}" by assuming there is only one line between markers (Bingo, START_WORD etc.). In the question, it is not necessary one line it could be "some lines" don't know how many.

Comment: The number of lines between the START and END doesn't matter and not counted for.  The variable holds three pieces of information: in the block, Bingo1 seen and Bingo2 seen. This trick won't work if you have multiple Bingo1 or 2s. Alternatively you can have three different variables to represent the same.

Comment: Ohk, I missed to see b==7.